# Gwt button need double click for load all data in a div

Tags: javascript, css, gwt

In my application i have a super user that can manage the entire software.
When the logged user is the admin he can see some Buttons for do that (manage).

The problem is with one of this button, the administration button, that when fired he must show an hidden div and load inside him few buttons.
When i click the "administration" button he load only the div and if i click it again he load the rest of the code (the buttons) and get blocket.

i think that the `DOM.getElementById("center_top").getStyle().setDisplay(Display.BLOCK);` block the rest of the code and i need another click for load the buttons.

Here is the code of the method:

```
package com.unibo.questionandanswer.client.view;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Display;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.unibo.questionandanswer.client.CategoriesInterface;
import com.unibo.questionandanswer.client.QuestionAndAnswer;
import com.unibo.questionandanswer.client.UsersService;
import com.unibo.questionandanswer.client.UsersServiceAsync;
import com.unibo.questionandanswer.shared.User;
import com.unibo.questionandanswer.shared.UserRights;

/**
 * 
 * @author Dario
 *
 */
public class AdminController {

    UserRights rightsFilter = UserRights.USER;

    private final UsersServiceAsync usersService = GWT
            .create(UsersService.class);

    private QuestionAndAnswer controller;

    public AdminController(CategoriesInterface categorie) {

        if (categorie instanceof QuestionAndAnswer) {
            this.controller = (QuestionAndAnswer) categorie.getController();
        }

        amministraSito();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void amministraSito() {

        // Bottone per l'admin gestione software
        final Button amministra = new Button("Amministra");
        final Button sitoNormale = new Button("Q&A Sito");

        RootPanel.get("top_header").add(amministra);
        RootPanel.get("top_header").add(sitoNormale);
        DOM.setElementAttribute(amministra.getElement(), "id",
                "amministraButton");
        DOM.setElementAttribute(sitoNormale.getElement(), "id",
                "backSitoButton");

        /**
         * Esce dalla modalità amministra
         */
        sitoNormale.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                controller.setSelectedImpostaCat(false);
                amministra.setEnabled(true);
                sitoNormale.setEnabled(false);
                Window.Location.reload();

            }
        });

        /**
         * Entra in modalità amministra
         */
        amministra.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                // RootPanel.get("center").clear();
                // DOM.getElementById("center_top").getStyle().setDisplay(Display.BLOCK);
                Document.get().getElementById("center_top").getStyle()
                        .setDisplay(Display.BLOCK);
                RootPanel.get("center_top").clear();
                // Util per promuovere giudici o rimuoverli
                giudiceUtil();
                // Util per rimuovere una risposta
                removeAnswerUtil();
                // Util per rimuovere una domanda
                removeQuestionUtil();
                // Util per modificare le categorie
                mangeTreeUtil();

                amministra.setEnabled(false);
                sitoNormale.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Metodo che permette all'admin di modificare le categorie
     */
    private void mangeTreeUtil() {

        // Bottone per l'admin gestione software
        final Button manageTree = new Button("Imposta categorie");

        RootPanel.get("center_top").add(manageTree);

        manageTree.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                RootPanel.get("center").clear();
                controller.setSelectedImpostaCat(true);
                controller.buildAdminTree();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Metodo che permette all'admin di rimuovere una domanda
     */
    private void removeQuestionUtil() {

    }

    /**
     * Metodo che permette all'admin di rimuovere una risposta
     */
    private void removeAnswerUtil() {

    }

    /**
     * Metodo che permette all'admi di selezionare un giudice o rimuoverlo
     */
    private void giudiceUtil() {

        // Bottone per inviare dati login al server-side
        final Button showUsers = new Button("All Users");

        RootPanel.get("center_top").add(showUsers);

        showUsers.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                controller.setSelectedImpostaCat(false);
                showAllRegisterdUsers();

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Metodo che motra tutti gli utenti registrati
     */
    private void showAllRegisterdUsers() {

        usersService.registeredUsers(new AsyncCallback<List<User>>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                String alert = "Errore in fase di registrazione";
                for (StackTraceElement el : caught.getStackTrace())
                    alert += "\n" + el.toString();

                Window.alert(alert);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<User> result) {

                RootPanel.get("center").clear();

                final Button users = new Button("Users");
                final Button giudici = new Button("Giudici");
                HorizontalPanel buttonFilter = new HorizontalPanel();

                buttonFilter.add(users);
                buttonFilter.add(giudici);

                RootPanel.get("center").add(buttonFilter);

                // Codice HTML che spiega il funzionamento del come fare
                HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
                HTML html = new HTML(
                        "<p style='margin-left: 20px'>Selezionare il nome utente per cambiare i suoi diritti da USER a GIUDICE e viceversa!</p><hr>");
                hp.add(html); // adds the widget to the panel

                RootPanel.get("center").add(hp);

                users.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                        rightsFilter = UserRights.USER;
                        showAllRegisterdUsers();
                        controller.setSelectedImpostaCat(false);

                    }
                });

                giudici.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                        rightsFilter = UserRights.GIUDICE;
                        showAllRegisterdUsers();
                        controller.setSelectedImpostaCat(false);

                    }
                });

                for (User curr : result) {

                    if (curr.get_userRight().equals(rightsFilter)) {

                        // Label per il dialog promozione a giudice
                        final Label textDialogGiud = new Label(
                                "Promuovere l'utente a Giudice?");
                        // Label per il dialog declassa a user
                        final Label textDialogGiudRemove = new Label(
                                "Declassare l'utente a User?");

                        // Bottone per promuovere user
                        final Button promuovi = new Button("Promuovi!");
                        // Bottone per declassare user
                        final Button declassa = new Button("Declassa!");
                        // Bottone per chiudere la dialog
                        final Button closeWindow = new Button("Chiudi");

                        // promuovi.getElement().setId("promuoviUser");
                        closeWindow.getElement().setId("chiudiDialog");

                        HorizontalPanel lineDialogText = new HorizontalPanel();
                        HorizontalPanel controllButtonsDialog = new HorizontalPanel();
                        FlowPanel flowPanelGiudice = new FlowPanel();

                        // Se l'utente selezionato è giudice carico i pulsanti
                        // per declassare
                        if (curr.get_userRight().equals(UserRights.GIUDICE)) {

                            controllButtonsDialog.add(declassa);
                            lineDialogText.add(textDialogGiudRemove);

                        } else if (curr.get_userRight().equals(UserRights.USER)) {
                            // Se l'utente selezionato è user carico i pulsanti
                            // per promuovere
                            controllButtonsDialog.add(promuovi);
                            lineDialogText.add(textDialogGiud);

                        }

                        // lineDialogText.add(textDialogGiud);
                        // controllButtonsDialog.add(promuovi);
                        controllButtonsDialog.add(closeWindow);
                        // Carico gli horizontal panel con i label e button che
                        // mi servono
                        // in base allo user
                        flowPanelGiudice.add(lineDialogText);
                        flowPanelGiudice.add(controllButtonsDialog);

                        final DialogBox dialogSelectGiud = new DialogBox();

                        dialogSelectGiud.setAnimationEnabled(true);

                        dialogSelectGiud.setWidget(flowPanelGiudice);

                        final HorizontalPanel userPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
                        final Label username = new Label(curr.getUsername());

                        // Handler che gestisce la gestione del click sulla
                        // lista
                        // di utenti o giudici
                        username.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                                dialogSelectGiud.setText("Selezionato: "
                                        + username.getText().toString());
                                dialogSelectGiud.center();
                                dialogSelectGiud.show();

                            }
                        });

                        userPanel.add(username);
                        RootPanel.get("center").add(userPanel);

                        /*
                         * BUTTON PROMUOVI UTENTE
                         */
                        promuovi.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                                dialogSelectGiud.hide();

                                usersService.findUser(username.getText()
                                        .toString(), new AsyncCallback<User>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                                        Window.alert("Errore nel trovare lo User!");

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(User result) {

                                        result.set_userRight(UserRights.GIUDICE);

                                        usersService.changeUserRights(result,
                                                new AsyncCallback<Void>() {

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onFailure(
                                                            Throwable caught) {

                                                        Window.alert("Errore nella promozione utente!");

                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(
                                                            Void result) {

                                                        Window.alert("Utente promosso a giudice!  "
                                                                + username
                                                                        .getText()
                                                                        .toString());

                                                        showAllRegisterdUsers();

                                                    }
                                                });

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });

                        /*
                         * BUTTON DECLASSA UTENTE
                         */
                        declassa.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                                dialogSelectGiud.hide();

                                usersService.findUser(username.getText()
                                        .toString(), new AsyncCallback<User>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                                        Window.alert("Errore nel trovare lo User!");

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(User result) {

                                        result.set_userRight(UserRights.USER);

                                        usersService.changeUserRights(result,
                                                new AsyncCallback<Void>() {

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onFailure(
                                                            Throwable caught) {

                                                        Window.alert("Errore nel declassare l'utente!");

                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(
                                                            Void result) {

                                                        Window.alert("Utente declassato a user!  "
                                                                + username
                                                                        .getText()
                                                                        .toString());

                                                        showAllRegisterdUsers();

                                                    }
                                                });

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });

                        /*
                         * BUTTON CHIUDI DIALOG PROMOZIONE
                         */
                        closeWindow.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                                dialogSelectGiud.hide();

                            }
                        });

                        /*
                         * QUALCHE CSS PER BUTTONS
                         */
                        userPanel.getElement().setAttribute("style",
                                "margin: auto; padding: 10px");
                        users.getElement().setAttribute("style",
                                "margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;");
                        giudici.getElement().setAttribute("style",
                                "margin: 5px 0 5px 5px; ");

                        //CSS per bottoni dentro dialogbox
                        controllButtonsDialog.setWidth("100%");
                        controllButtonsDialog.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);

                        promuovi.getElement().setAttribute("style",
                                "margin: 20px 5px 5px 5px; float: left;");
                        declassa.getElement().setAttribute("style",
                                "margin: 20px 5px 5px 5px; float: left;");
                        closeWindow.getElement().setAttribute("style",
                                "margin: 20px 5px 5px 5px; float: right;");

                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

And here the css that hide the "center_top" div

```
#center_top{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    display: none; 

}
```

Why only with this button i need a double click for show div and load buttons inside?

The DOM.getElementById block the execution of the code?

The browser console unrlined this line of code

```
  /**
   * Adds a widget to the detach list. This is the list of widgets to be
   * detached when the page unloads.
   * 
   * <p>
   * This method must be called for all widgets that have no parent widgets.
   * These are most commonly {@link RootPanel RootPanels}, but can also be any
   * widget used to wrap an existing element on the page. Failing to do this may
   * cause these widgets to leak memory. This method is called automatically by
   * widgets' wrap methods (e.g.
   * {@link Button#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)}).
   * </p>
   * 
   * <p>
   * This method may <em>not</em> be called on any widget whose element is
   * contained in another widget. This is to ensure that the DOM and Widget
   * hierarchies cannot get into an inconsistent state.
   * </p>
   * 
   * @param widget the widget to be cleaned up when the page closes
   * @see #detachNow(Widget)
   */
  public static void detachOnWindowClose(Widget widget) {
    assert !widgetsToDetach.contains(widget) : "detachOnUnload() called twice "
        + "for the same widget";
    assert !isElementChildOfWidget(widget.getElement()) : "A widget that has "
        + "an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list";

    widgetsToDetach.add(widget);
  }
```

Comment: If you can click the button second time it means that it is still enabled. So your code doesn't reach `amministra.setEnabled(false);` line. You should check the error console in your browser.

Comment: added the error of the browser console, can you help me to understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you get an error while adding a widget to the detach list.

First you need to know what the detach list is. It is explained in the comment to the `detachOnWindowClose` method. I'll try to explain this in a simpler way.

Whenever you use a widget that is displayed on the page, the widget creates a DOM ([Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)) structure and is connected with it. For example the widget has the code for event handlers. GWT needs to keep control over that connection so when the DOM is removed (for example the page is cleared or unloaded - in general *detached*) it could free the memory used by previously said event handlers (or other resources). Otherwise it could lead to memory leak.

Widgets must be added to the detach list when they have no parent widgets

- when you directly add a widget to the DOM by the RootPanel (`RootPanel.get().add(widget);` or just `RootPanel.get("element_id");`)
- when you wrap the widget around existing DOM element (`Panel.wrap(element);`)

The widgets contained in other widgets are detached by the parent widget.

---

If you get an error while adding a widget to the detach list it could mean that you meet one of two conditions:

- the widget is already in the detach list
- you try to create a widget with the DOM element that is a part of another widget.

You need to know that when you call `RootPanel.get("center_top");` you are actually using the RootPanel widget connected with DOM element with `center_top` id. That means that next time you call `RootPanel.get("center_top");` you will get an error because it would already be in the detach list. Furthermore, if you call `RootPanel.get(id);` with the id of the element contained in `center_top` element you would also get an error because it would already had a parent widget created by the first call of the `RootPanel.get("center_top");` method.

---

I hope that now you get the idea of what the detach list is and I also hope I wouldn't get down-voted for such simplified explanation ;)

---

Now let's get back to your problem. I suppose that one of 
`giudiceUtil();`, `removeAnswerUtil();`, `removeQuestionUtil();` or `mangeTreeUtil();` methods meets conditions to raise an error mentioned above.

You can get around by reusing `RootPanel`s once created by previous calls (don't call `RootPanel.get()` with the same id twice) or by creating them in bottom-up order (that means that first you get a RootPanel of child element and then the parent element).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, another point of view is always accepted from me :D .

In the `giudiceUtil()` and `manageTreeUtil()` all two call the method `RootPanel.get("center_top")` for positionate the elements (different element).

So the problem is that i call not only 1 time the `RootPanel.get()` , but i call it 3 times and i get this errors?

I try some change, if i solve the problem i check your answer! Now i upvote this for the explanation ;)

Comment: Anyway i commented the functions `giudiceUtil()` and `mangetreeUtil()` and the problem still remain.... so they aren't the problem...i try to edit the post with more code maybe you can see the problem easy :D

Edited the java code!